# Generate a new list with key

Tags: c#, .net, list

i would like to create a new list with key and values

```
List<object> r = new List<object>();  
r.Add("apple");  
r.Add("John");  
return r;
```

when u Addwatch the r, you will see

```
[1] = apple  
[2] = John
```

Questions: How do i make the [1] and [2] to be new key? When i addwatch the r, i would like to see [1] is replaced by Name. something as below:

```
Name = apple  
TeacherName = John
```

Comment: Your question is very difficult to understand - try clearing up what you are trying to say. It sounds like you want a Dictionary, that allows you to use a key/value pair

Comment: Please look into this question, can be more helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/q/58669733/5932176

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do you mean you want to use something like [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

example:

```
Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
d.Add("Name", "Apple");
d.Add("Teacher", "John");
```

or do you want an object to more strongly typed?
in this case you have to use your one class / struct

```
class MyObject
{
 public string Name {get; set;}
 public string Teacher {get; set;}
}
```

Then

```
var list = new List<MyObject>();
list.Add(new MyObject { Name = "Apple", Teacher = "John" });
list.Add(new MyObject { Name = "Banana", Teacher = "Setphan" });
```

then you can all it

```
var item = list[0];
var name = item.Name;
var teacher = item.Teacher;
```

Answer (score 3):

It is completely incorrect to use a list for this kind of a data structure. You need to use use [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) , [NameValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx) or similar type.

Answer (score 2):

You can transform your list:

```
List<object> r = new List<object>();
r.Add("apple");
r.Add("John");
r.Add("orange");
r.Add("Bob");

var dict = r.Where((o, i) => i % 2 == 0)
    .Zip(r.Where((o, i) => i % 2 != 0), (a, b) => new { Name = a.ToString(), TeacherName = b.ToString() });

foreach (var item in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

---

Output:

```
{ Name = apple, TeacherName = John }
{ Name = orange, TeacherName = Bob }
```

---

And then transform to dictionary:

```
var result = dict.ToDictionary(d => d.Name, d => d.TeacherName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a Dictionary to do this. Not a List.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I hope i dont make any syntax mistakes here...

```
Dictionary <string, int> r = new Dictionary<string,int>();
r.add("apple",1);
r.add("John",2)
console.WriteLine(r["apple"]);//returns value 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear and hard to understand.

Do you mean to say you want keys instead of indexes ? Like Name instead of 1

Well then as [Aliza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807815/aliza) and [Bumble Bee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/211527/bumble-bee) have said you need to use a Dictionary instead of a List.

Here's a small example

```
IDictionary<string, Interval> store = new Dictionary<string, string>();

store.Add("Name","apple");
store.Add("TeacherName ", John);

foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> e in store)
     Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", e.Key, e.Value);
```